# What tense use before and after "then"?

Tags: past-tense

Which sentence is correct?

1) The arrangements had been made and then the guests have arrived.

2) The arrangements had been made and then the guests arrived.

If I use "then" the time is somehow determined, so I should use past simple. Am I right? 
Is past perfect justified here?

Comment: "2) The arrangements had been made and then the guests arrived." is correct. You could also say, "The arrangements were made and then the guests arrived."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to your sentence the first action that had happened was making the arrangements and the second action was the guests arrival so as a fact that both occured in past for the first one you should use past perfect and for the second one past simple so the second sentence is correct:
The arrangements had been made then the guests arrived

Comment: In my point of view you can't use have arrived with past perfect because the first part of your sentence is refering to an action which had happened before another one in the past and in the second part you're trying to join the first part of your sentence with an action which you can see its results in the peresent time or in other words to an action which has continued up to the peresent time which is not feasible

Answer (score -1):

The second sentence *The arrangements had been made and then the guests arrived* is correct since we often use the past perfect tense when we talk about an action took place before other one in the past. *the arrangement* took place before arriving the guests.

Comment: "then the guests have arrived" makes no sense in American English, in any circumstance.